# PUT method not post data ShopifyAPI

Tags: curl, shopify, put

I am using ShopifyAPI using CURL, I had integrated API for Create product and remove product using POST and DELETE method respectively but when I use PUT method for modify product as mentioned below

```
curl -i  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"product":{"title":"sadasasdasdasasd","vendor":"Test Drobe","body_html":"testtest<\/p>","product_type":"Health & Fitness","variants":{"price":"250","inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"continue","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"fulfillment_service":"manual","title":"1"},"id":"120393158"}}' https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxx@myshop.myshopify.com/admin/products/120393158.json
```

I am getting below output

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 06 Feb 2013 05:52:34 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit: 3/500
HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_API_CALL_LIMIT: 3/500
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: e3942aa30d0979a09d6e155ea5b837cd
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Set-Cookie: _secure_session_id=3bf98f1b3303d585a2af7aac5c0a1107; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-Runtime: 0.049121
```

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an error in how the API is handling variants.  On inspection of the variants in your request it appears that you are passing in incorrect data.

It should be:

`"variants": [{variant_information}]`

Even still, a 500 isn't what should be raised in this situation it should've been a 422.

Let me know if this helps you with your problem